# Walk mode camera "jumps" back when stopped

Tags: workflow, camera, video

I am quite new to Blender and I don't know if this is some setting I messed up or a bug.

When I use walk mode/fly with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> it all works fine, but when I want to stop and go inside a wall for example and stop to look at a certain detail the camera always jumps a bit behind where I am and down... I have looked everywhere in the *User Preferences* and found nothing to change this jump.

When I create a new Blender project walk mode works as it should again. It gets really frustrating since I can never position myself with walk mode, I always end up inside a wall or somewhere so that I can't see the detail I am trying to work with.

[image: Example Screencast]
Here you can see me trying to look at the edge of the building. When I stop flymode/walkmode, it pushes me into the edge.

Comment: FWIW, in addition to this camera jumping issue, I also was hitting Walk mode issues like it making objects disappear via frustum/occlusion culling even when they weren't occluded / outside of the camera frustum. These also disappeared when switching to ortho and back per BlackInkStudio's answer, and I think they are caused by the same issue. I believe Blender is keeping some floating point offset stored in Walk mode that grows in error over time (always repros in projects I've had open for days) and switching to ortho and back resets this offset, fixing the issue

Answer (score 5):

I'm using blender 2.78a.  I've been dealing with the same issue, and I found a work around.

If I zoom all of the way in **before** entering fly mode, the "jumping" no longer occurs.  If I zoom out before entering fly mode, the "jumping" gets worse.

Answer (score 1):

If you <kbd>RMB</kbd> click it cancels `Fly Mode` and resets the view (jumps) back to the starting position.

If you <kbd>LMB</kbd> click it accepts your new new position.

*Note: in newer versions of Blender the key combination has been changed to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>*

https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/navigate/index.html

https://vimeo.com/9567714

Comment: Hmm yeah but my problem is that my left click is jumping me back just a bit, enough to displace me when iam doing detail work :/

Comment: @Ganonflake you may need to include a screencast/gif of the problem; I'm not able to replicate that here with Fly/Walk.

Comment: There's a possibility that this problem is related to the mouse itself, specially if you have a mouse software, could be conflicting with Blender, I had the same issue in different software, are you sure this glitch happens only in Fly mode?

Comment: @Georges This happens in both walk and fly mode. Everything works fine while flying/walking but when i stop it always pushes me in some direction, sometimes the "jump" is longer then other times. 

With a new project this jump is not present, everything works fine then, maybe i should just move all my content to a new blender file...

I will upload a gif in a moment!

Comment: Try confirming with Enter button instead of left mouse button, just to isolate the purpose

Comment: @Georges enter button also triggers the jump :/

Comment: If you attach the .Blend file, I can test it on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>  to switch to orthographic view. Then from their just back to perspective view and your problem should be fixed.

Comment: This is the correct solution. It looks like Blender somehow gets into a bad state and this resets it, eliminating the jumping even when you're back in perspective / continue zooming. I wonder if it's floating point drift of the WASD offset that accumulates over time of using Walk

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to *Edit > Preferences > Navigation*
2. Change Zoom method inside zoom tab to Scale