# While editing my model, my camera jumps?

Tags: camera

So I'm editing a model and for a while now, the camera seems to "jump" to a different view whenever I click. I'm using the shift+F method for moving the camera, I'll move the view to see some vertices better to continue working and when I click the mouse to stop using the camera it jumps to a view that is really off.

For example, the area I'm working on(on the model) is the area I've circled in red and this is after I've pressed Shift+F and in free-roam camera mode(I think that's what it's called)

And this happens when I click to exit free roam camera to work on the model
[image]

So any ideas on how to fix this? I've changed the clipping distance minimum so I could get this close to edit(otherwise the vertices vanish) so please don't say to go to default, otherwise I can't do the internal work on the model.

Update: I know clicking with the right mouse button resets the initial position and no, I've been clicking with the left, not right button.
Update: The fix/answer was posted in this question:
[Walk mode camera "jumps" back when stopped](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51474/walk-mode-camera-jumps-back-when-stopped)

In short, scroll as far in with the mouse wheel as you can, then it won't happen. That causes the camera to jump.

Comment: When you say "And this happens when I click to exit free roam camera to work on the model"... if you use the right mouse button you will come back to your initial position. Use the left one to validate your current flying position

Comment: Yes, I do click with the left mouse and I know the right one resets the position but what I'm saying is, the camera always does this regardless.

Comment: Can you reproduce that behaviour with the default file ? Or does it happen only with that one ? It would help if you [upload](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) problem file and include a link here. Either way you can use `Numpad period` or `Shift`+`B` shortcuts for centering view, see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/696/how-to-reset-the-center-of-rotation-of-the-3d-view-when-it-is-not-the-center

Comment: I cannot upload the model because it's for an upcoming game and I've had past experiences of people stealing them but from what I've seen it's just this file that's playing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Walk mode camera "jumps" back when stopped](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51474/walk-mode-camera-jumps-back-when-stopped)

The fix/answer was posted in this question: Walk mode camera "jumps" back when stopped

In short, scroll as far in with the mouse wheel as you can, then it won't happen. That causes the camera to jump.